# Embed a font from an SVG image in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, svg, fonts, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 4 and have an SVG image which references an external font. Here is the file structure:

```
app 
 |
  --- assets  
        | --- images  
                 | --- myImage.svg  
                 | --- MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.woff
```

I am referencing the font from the SVG file as such:

`<![CDATA[@font-face {
            font-family: 'Myriad Pro Bold Condensed';
            src: local("Myriad Pro Bold Condensed"), url("MYRIADPRO-BOLDCOND.woff") format('woff');
                }
                ]]>`

When I run the app, the image is found but the associated font is not so the image looks weird. There is no error that is thrown. I've tried throwing these files in public/image, putting the font in its own /fonts folder and all sorts of mixing and matching, to no avail. When I view the svg directly in Chrome it has the correct font.

What is the appropriate way to embed a font in an SVG in rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the SVG?  Is it as an `<img>`?  If so, browser security restrictions prevent the SVG from referencing other files.  The SVG has to be self contained.  You should be able to do that by embedding the font as a data URL.

Comment: I'm using an img tag. How do I embed the font as a data URL? Where should my font file be relative to my image in rails? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Oh man I just realized.. I was confused because I am able to reference a font file from SVG on another website that doesn't use Rails. But I just realized I used an object tag there. Will try that out.

Comment: Yes, an `<object>` should work better.  But in answer to your question, search "font data uri" on here and you will get plenty of answers on how to do that if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Using an object tag to call the SVG allows calling an external font file.

So in my html.erb file I reference the image in an object tag:

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="<%= asset_path 'image.svg' %>"></object>`

The SVG file, and my file structure is the same as I mentioned in my question.